# How to Export Gridview Data in Pdf in DotNetNuke(DNN)?

Tags: dotnetnuke

How to Export Gridview Data in Pdf in DotNetNuke(DNN)?

The Code Behind code are:-

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PurchaseOrderDetails.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView gridview1 = new GridView();

gridview1.AllowPaging = false;
//DataSet ds = objOrderRegistratonController.GetOrders();                
grddisplay.DataBind();
grddisplay.RenderControl(hw);
grddisplay.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
grddisplay.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
grddisplay.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
grddisplay.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
grddisplay.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

The Error Comes:-
control of type 'gridview' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

I also try to used this method as many give solutions, its problem of rendering of gridview
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
       {
          //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
       }

But this method gives error in DNN  'MPPR.mpprcms_OrderRegistraton.ViewPurchaseOrder.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control)': no suitable method found to override

Please give Suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the DotNetNuke wrapper control for the telerik grid which supports exporting to various formats. I don't use the wrapper but it might help you with what you are trying to achieve.

Link on how to use the wrapper

[That's Too Easy - Implementing DNNGrid (aka Telerik RadGrid)](http://www.tressleworks.ca/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/77/Thats-Too-Easy-Implementing-DNNGrid-aka-Telerik-RadGrid.aspx)

Link regarding the telerik radgrid control for exporting.

[Telerik RadGrid - Export to PDF](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)

{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */ 
}

protected void GeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
    GridView1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
    GridView1.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
    GridView1.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream); pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();     
}
```